# Maximum leaf number of an $m \times n$ grid graph?

Tags: graph-theory

Are there any results regarding the [maximum leaf number](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MaximumLeafNumber.html) of an $m \times n$ two-dimensional [grid graph](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GridGraph.html)?

Either a closed form, or a table of values for small $m$ and $n$?

Comment: Just a few remarks.  The leaf number is $2$ if $m=1$ and $n>1$.  For $m=2$ and $n\geq 2$, the leaf number is $n$.  For $m=n=3$, it is easy to show that the leaf number is $6$, and I would guess that, for $m=3$ and $n\geq 3$, the answer is $2n$.  I expect the leaf number to grow linearly in $m+n$.

Comment: Indeed, for $m=3$ and $n\geq 3$, the answer is $2n$.

Comment: Every non-leaf can support at most two leaves; this gives an upper bound. On the other hand, a (nearly) regular solution where every third row or column is an antenna with two rows of leaves on either side is easy to construct; this gives a lower bound. Both are of the order of $\frac23mn$, so only details remain to be worked out. (On the other hand, since you're looking for a table for small $m$ and $n$, perhaps the details are what you're interested in. :-)

Comment: @joriki, you are quite right with your construction suggestion.  So, if $n\geq m$, we have the leaf number to be at least $2\left\lfloor \frac{m}{3}\right\rfloor (n-1) + t$, where $t=2$ if $m\equiv 0\pmod{3}$ or $m\equiv 1\pmod{3}$, and $t=n$ if $m\equiv 2\pmod{3}$.  By the way, it is possible for a non-leaf to support three leaves. That happens rarely, though.

Comment: @Batominovski: Ah, yes, I missed that. So it's a bit more complicated than I thought.

Comment: Here's a paper on this subject: http://www.cs.umanitoba.ca/~lipakc/gridgraph-aug6-08.pdf

Comment: @Batominovski: A non-leaf supports $3$ leaves only if it is a leaf of the tree of non-leaves and lies in the interior of the grid. Perhaps one could use this in some form of recursion.